# When is chr(ord(c)) not equal to c in Python?

Tags: python

I am reading the source code of `testinfra` in the [Ansible](https://github.com/philpep/testinfra/blob/55e4ed92db8cc9fe118fe3da465010169825b0d6/testinfra/backend/ansible.py#L40) module. I found the following lines of code:

```
    # Ansible return an unicode object but this is bytes ...
    # A simple test case is:
    # >>> assert File("/bin/true").content == open("/bin/true").read()
    stdout_bytes = b"".join((chr(ord(c)) for c in out['stdout']))
    stderr_bytes = b"".join((chr(ord(c)) for c in out['stderr']))
```

It iterates over `stdout`, gets the integer ordinal of each character and converts it back to a one-character string.  But what's the point?

Comment: Python version probably matters here. In Python2, ord takes unicode characters as input, but chr only goes from int to ASCII, so there may be taking advantage of some weirdness there?

Comment: It would help to point out where in the code you saw that line. There's not much we can do without context. I'm assuming you're referring to the code in the [Ansible](https://github.com/philpep/testinfra/blob/55e4ed92db8cc9fe118fe3da465010169825b0d6/testinfra/backend/ansible.py#L40) module... the comment there could have been useful.

Comment: @JeffMercado Yes, it's in the ansible backend source code. I've read the comment, but why does the author use this? Is it equal to `out['stdout'].encode('ascii')`?

Answer (score 5):

When `c` is unicode-specific character (cannot be encoded in ASCII):

```
>>> ord(u'\u2020')
8224
>>> chr(ord(u'\u2020'))
ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)
```

This is only true in [Python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr), as in [Python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr), unichr is removed and chr acts as unichr. This seems to be unusual behavior for such a library, since it would routinely throw an unexpected error that's executable-specific for any non-English locale.